# Is there a simple/elegant way to have approval processes that span Salesforce instances?

Tags: api, integration

Imagine that you have 12-15 different Salesforce instances all customized for different companies and workflows but that some approvals need to be executed outside of the instances.  Right now the approvers need to have logins to each individual instance and it is cumbersome and irritating.  Would it be best to have a 16th Salesforce instance just for approvals and build connectors to bring them across or is there some sort of external lightweight approval application that all of the instances could use ?  Integrating all 15 companies instances is a non-starter.

We are not trying to avoid license seats, just looking for the most elegant way to solve this problem so that approvers have one place to go to approve things presented in a consistent manner.  We would like the system to be securable and have a preference for approval flows that do not utilize email.

Any constructive advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or you can deploy an Idp Provider that authenticates all users and then they don't have to remember passwords